# Como Muestro la informacion de la api en una modal

Tags: javascript

ya consulte la API y tengo información mostrada en una card, pero quisiera saber como podria mostrarla en una modal cuando le de click a alguna de estas tarjetas, no se si me hago entender pero lo explicó un poco mas abajo

les comparto el codigo que tengo de js:

```
//Variables y selectores

    const header = document.querySelector('.header');
    const logo = document.querySelector('.logo');
    const navegacion = document.querySelector('.navegacion');
    const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
    const contenedorTarjetas = document.querySelector('.contenedor__tarjetas-pais');
    
    //Eventos 
    
    menu.addEventListener('click', activarMenu);
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', generarPeticion);
    
    
    //Funciones
    
    function activarMenu() {
        header.classList.toggle('header-active');
        logo.classList.toggle('logo-active');
        navegacion.classList.toggle('navegacion-active');
        menu.classList.toggle('menu-active');
    
        if (navegacion.classList.contains('navegacion')) {
            navegacion.classList.remove('navegacion');
        } else {
            navegacion.classList.add('navegacion')
        }
    }
    
    function generarPeticion() {
    
        const url = 'https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all';
        fetch(url)
            .then(respuesta => respuesta.json())
            .then(datos => mostrarDatos(datos))
    }
    
    function mostrarDatos(datos) {
    
        
     const { translations: { spa: { official } }, flags: { svg } } = datos;
        datos.forEach(pais => {
            const { translations: { spa: { official } }, flags: { svg } } = pais;
            const div = document.createElement('div');
            div.classList.add('tarjeta__pais');
            div.innerHTML = `
            <div class="tarjetapais__imagen">
            <img src="${svg}" alt="" class="pais">
            </div>
            <h2 class="nombre__pais">${official}</h2>`;
            contenedorTarjetas.appendChild(div);
        });
    
       const div = document.querySelectorAll('.tarjeta__pais');
    for (let i = 0; i < div.length; i++) {
        div[i].addEventListener('click', () =>{
            console.log(svg)
        });
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

estas son las cards, quisiera que al darle click se abra una modal y me arroje mas informacion de la API, agradezco la ayuda, solo quisiera saber si es posible

Comment: Si por supuesto que si!! exactamente igual a como lo estas haciendo, pero pasando la info al modal...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Usas un [dialog](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog)
2. Guardas las lista de paises en una variable global (PAISES)
3. Creas una función `showDialog`, que recibe como argumento el índex del array PAIS. agregas el contenido deseado dentro del `dialog`
4. En la lista de banderas colocas un evento `onclick` junto con el índex

Ejemplo:

```js
const Dialogo = {
  modal: document.getElementById("modal"),
  content: document.getElementById("modal-content")
};

function generarPeticion() {
  const url = 'https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all';
  fetch(url)
      .then(respuesta => respuesta.json())
      .then(datos => mostrarDatos(datos))
}

let PAISES=[];
function mostrarDatos(datos) {
  PAISES = datos;
  datos.forEach( (pais,i) => {
      const div = document.createElement('div');
      div.classList.add('tarjeta__pais');
      div.innerHTML = `
      <div class="tarjetapais__imagen" onclick="showDialog(${i})">
      <img src="${pais.flags.svg}" alt="" class="pais">
      </div>
      <h2 class="nombre__pais">${pais.translations.spa.official}</h2>`;
      contenedorTarjetas.appendChild(div);
  });
}
function showDialog(id){
  let pais = PAISES[id];
   Dialogo.content.innerHTML = `
    <p>Nombre: ${pais.translations.spa.official}</p>
    <p>Continente: ${pais.region}</p>
    <p>Mapa: <a href="${pais.maps.googleMaps}">Google maps</a></p>
  `;
  Dialogo.modal.showModal();
}

generarPeticion();
```

```css
#contenedorTarjetas{
  display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(min(100px,50%),1fr));
    width: 100%;
    gap:4px;
}
img{
  width:100%;
}
h2{
 font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;

}
.tarjeta__pais{
 padding:10px
}
dialog::backdrop {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(
    45deg,
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 1px,
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 1px,
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 20px
  );
  backdrop-filter: blur(3px);
}

dialog{   
    transform: translateY(-1000px);
    transition: all 0.6s;
}

dialog[open] {   
    transform: translateY(0);
}
```

```html
<div id="contenedorTarjetas"></div>

<dialog id="modal">
  <article id="modal-content"></article>
  <form method="dialog">
    <button>Close</button>
  </form>
</dialog>
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias 